# Cast to Interface type in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can we typecast to an interface type in VBA?

```
Public Function createArray(ParamArray args() As Variant) As IArray

    Dim arr As IArray
    Set arr = New cRwArray

    Select Case UBound(args)

        'No params
        Case -1
            'Create decorator for empty array (no action required)

        '1 params
        Case 0
            'Return array with range values
            If TypeName(args(0)) = "cRwRange" Then
                'Cast type
                Dim range As iRange
                range = ctype(args(0), iRange) 'IRange variable not defined
                Call arr.readFromRange(range)

    End Select
    Set createArray = arr
End Function
```

Edit: this is strange.

```
Sub test()

    Dim arr As IArray
    Dim range As iRange

    Set range = createRange("Sheet1", 20, 30)
    Set arr = createArray(range)

End Sub
```

Yet, the type is not correctly set.
I checked this in the factory:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(args(0)) 'cRwRange, not the interface type?
```

Comment: You don't need to - just assign the object using `Set`.

Comment: @Rory Doesn't seem to help unfortunately. The compiler complains about `IRange` not being recognized as a type. It exists though, no complaint when declaring the `range as IRange`.

Comment: What's the error message with `Set range = args(0)`

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `TypeName` does. It returns the actual declared type of an object. You want `TypeOf` if you just want to test whether an object implements a particular interface.

Comment: @Rory Oow, that's it. Thanks :-) Indd, also didn't have to cast with cType. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly cast the object, as simple assignment will work:

```
Set range = args(0)
```

Additionally, `TypeName` returns the declared type of an object; if you want to know whether a given object implements a specific interface, you use `TypeOf`:

```
If TypeOf range Is iRange Then
```

for example. Also note that `range` is really not a good name for a variable in Excel... :)